# mime-type missing in mailsend email client

Tags: email, command-line-interface, mime-types, email-client

I'm using "mailsend v.1.19" to text a webmail client.
When I set mime-type, whether is with message body or one line message, I cannot find any trace of it into the raw email.

e,g:

```
mailsend -smtp local-mail.com -f sender@sender.local -t receiver@receiver.local -sub "Another Test Email With HTML body and mime type set from file body" -msg-body ~/justbody.html -starttls -user xxx -pass xxxx -mime-type "text/html"
```

I'm deliberately not setting content-type for testing purposes.

My SMPT ingestor will get the following raw stream with no signs of "text-html":

```
Received: from localhost (unknown [10.91.142.1])
by local-mail.dev.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS
for receiver@receiver.local; Wed, 31 Jan 2018 11:37:10 +0000 (UTC)
Subject: Another Test Email With HTML body and mime type set from file body
From: sender@sender.local
Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 11:37:10 +0000
To: receiver@receiver.local
X-Mailer: @(#) mailsend v1.19 (Unix)
X-Copyright: BSD. It is illegal to use this software for Spamming
Mime-version: 1.0
Content-Type: (null); charset=utf-8
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did you try moving the `-mime-type` declaration before `-attach`? From looking at the documentation, it's looking vaguely like perhaps this makes a difference.

Comment: there are no attachments, this is mime-type setting for the email itself.

Comment: there is another option for that :
-attach file,mime_type,[i/a] (i=inline,a=attachment)

Comment: Right, so, did you try putting the `-mime-type` before `-msg-body`?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using mailsend with both parameters -content-type and mime-type both placed before the message body in the command line.
The result is that the header Content-type is filled with mime-type value.

So when mime-type is set, content-type header contains its value, when both are set, content-type still takes the mime-type parameter value and ignores the content-type.

I believe this issue is related to mailsend clean in documentation what is the logic behind it.

Comment: I can't really parse this in any detail, but the gist seems to be that you have found a bug. Points for [reporting it](https://github.com/muquit/mailsend/issues/128)